# Forwarding IP address to proper domain in Apache 2.4 / Centos 7

Tags: apache, centos7, httpd.conf

I want to forward any requests for my server public IP address to the domain.  I have the following code near the top of the `httpd.conf` file.  The numbers in the second line are the actual IP address of the server.

However, when I visit the IP address in my browser, (1.2.3.4 in this example case) the website comes up with the IP and no https.  Why does this code below not forward the request to the domain with https?

If the user visits http:// or https://1.2.3.4 I want them to be redirected to https://www.example.com.

```
# Rewrite engine to move the raw IP address to URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: if it is not doing it you are configuring it under the wrong context. The most simple approach would be to have a virtualhost with servername 1.2.3.4 and a simple `Redirect / https://www.example.com/`, that for those requesting 1.2.3.4, for the rest.. the firstly defined port 80 virtualhost wih the same redirect will do.

Comment: the rationale behind this is that apache is when a request arrives apache looks at the host header if there is no match in servername directive in any of the defined virtualhosts, the first virtualhost is used. My recommendation is whenerver possible try to address your traffic through different virtualhosts instead of "catch-all" mod-rewrite recipes which most times can end in pain.

Comment: Thanks, I moved it to the Vhost and it worked great.  I was using Let's Encrypt for TLS certs and I guess on Centos, when it configures Apache, it loads the *:80 vhost from sites-enabled directory, but loads *:443 from sites-available directory.